# Django ImageField.url returning URL with expiration querystring instead of plain url

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a simple Model for storing a Client's Logo in my system. I am running into an issue where the returned `file.url` value is also providing expiration querystring parameters and occasionally it expires before the client logs out of the system so they get a 404 error.

With that, I cannot figure out how to disable the querystring from being added other than by either building the URL manually (which probably isn't the best option as Django provides the URL), or by doing (what I have done) and parsed the querystring off from the URL before storing it.

Can someone explain what is going on here? - I use Digital Ocean Spaces if that matters but it shouldn't as my static files are stored there as well and there is no expiration set on those files once they are loaded.

Here is the model with the upload path:

```
# for client logo uploads
def logo_upload_path(instance, filename):
    # client_name/ClientLogo/logo.[png, jpg, ...]
    return f'{instance.client_url}/ClientLogo/logo.{filename.split(".")[-1]}'


class ClientLogo(models.Model):
    """
    Basically a singleton class, I only want 1 logo per client
    """
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=logo_upload_path,)
    client_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # already saved
        if self.pk is not None:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # new entry, so let's overwrite the old one
            self.pk = 1
            # the pk is set so let's save it now
            self.save()
```

Here is how I gather the values needed to display the logo on my page:

```
logo = ClientLogo.objects.first()
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
print(logo.file.url)   # https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/files/fake_client/ClientLogo/logo.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=VKJKW2WZIJMEVGNH276A%2F20200902%2Fsfo2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200902T134822Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a41658ab1df043a56910162428cc732aec2be1eb8659b958485138200150ee27

only_url = urljoin(logo.file.url, urlparse(logo.file.url).path)
request.session['client_logo_path'] = only_url

# only_url =  https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com/files/fake_client/ClientLogo/logo.png
```

Here are the storage settings:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '----'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '----'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'sfo2'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
# look at storage backends to determine the location
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storage_backends.ClientStorage'


class ClientStorage(S3Boto3Storage, ABC):
    print(ABC.__dict__)
    print(S3Boto3Storage.__dict__)
    # cache is only done in production, debug is still there for the time being...
    if hasattr(settings, 'CACHE') and settings.CACHE is False:
        bucket_name = 'dev_bucket'
    else:
        bucket_name = 'client_bucket'
```

Comment: How is your storage configured in settings? Looks like it's backed onto S3 judging by the AWS signature params

Comment: @markwalker_ added but it isn't much different than default values